# Как массив влияет на Map коллекцию? Java

Tags: java, map

Есть вот такой код.

```
public class CSVtestclass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    String FileName = "c:\\TestJava\\report.csv";

    File file = new File(FileName);



    try (BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String reader;
        String wordName;
        String wordCount;
        HashMap<String, int[]> stringIntegerHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        read.readLine();
        while ((reader = read.readLine()) != null) {
            try {

                String[] next = reader.split(";");
                wordName = next[10];
                wordCount= next[17];
                wordCount = wordCount.replace("\"", "");
                if (stringIntegerHashMap.containsKey(wordName)) {
                    int[] ints = stringIntegerHashMap.get(wordName);
                    ints[0]++;
                    ints[1] += Integer.parseInt(wordCount);
                } else {
                    stringIntegerHashMap.put(wordName, new int[]{1, Integer.parseInt(wordCount)});
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, int[]> pair : stringIntegerHashMap.entrySet()) {
            int[] value = pair.getValue();
            System.out.printf("%s zayavki: %d interakcii: %d%n", pair.getKey(), value[0], value[1]);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

Никак не могу понять каким образом массиву []ints  удается влиять на результат элементов stringIntegerHashMap ??? Ведь он просто "для себя работает" грубо говоря. Т.е. его результат никуда не присваивается, но тем не менее ему удается это делать- а именно суммировать значения ключей в мапе.

```
` if (stringIntegerHashMap.containsKey(wordName)) {
                    int[] ints = stringIntegerHashMap.get(wordName);
                    ints[0]++;
                    ints[1] += Integer.parseInt(wordCount);
                } else {
                    stringIntegerHashMap.put(wordName, new int[]{1, Integer.parseInt(wordCount)});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массивы, даже примитивов, это уже объекты. Объекты хранятся в куче, в переменных хранятся только ссылки на эти объекты.

Поэтому этой строкой

```
int[] ints = stringIntegerHashMap.get(wordName);
```

массив `ints` ссылается на тот же массив, что и лежит в `Map`. Любое изменение внутренностей массива `ints` изменит сам массив в куче. Эти изменения отразятся во всех переменных, которые ссылаются на этот же массив.

Comment: Я просто читаю этот код так:  Если встречаем в словаре ключ "А", то создаем массив ints и присваиваем ему массив int[]={1, wordCount}. Потом ints[0]++;
ints[1] += Integer.parseInt(wordCount);  .Т.е получается  ints - это уже объект в куче, а не локальная переменная какая-то?

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan Если **не** встречаем ... Когда такой же ключ попадется в следующий раз, новый массив не создаем, а достаем ссылку на ранее созданный массив из словаря.

Comment: Ну как нет, если написано:  if (stringIntegerHashMap.containsKey(wordName)

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan Массив **создается** в `else`.

Comment: Я хотел сказать объявляется массив ints. Для меня это равнозначно было "создается"  до этого времени.

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan Но теперь-то Вы видите, что это разные вещи?

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan создаете и объявляете массив вы в else, в if вы его получаете и кладете в ints

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за терпение и труд

Answer (score 3):

Здесь Вы кладете новую ссылку на массив в словарь под ключом `wordName`

```
stringIntegerHashMap.put(wordName, new int[]{1, Integer.parseInt(wordCount)});
```

а здесь достаете ее по ключу `wordName`

```
int[] ints = stringIntegerHashMap.get(wordName);
```

Массив - ссылочный тип, так что здесь:

```
ints[0]++;
ints[1] += Integer.parseInt(wordCount);
```

Вы работаете со ссылкой на него, a ссылка в словаре указывает туда же.